# How to get api key by the key and not the id AWS APIGateway

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I'm using Go sdk but an example with any other sdk will be helpfull anyway.

I'm trying to access an API Key by the Value but I don't see any way of doing this. Apparently the only way of getting and API Key is by it's id with the `GetApiKey` method or using the name in the `GetApiKeys` method.

I don't want this, I want to access to the API Key using the Value itself. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I found out that the sdk has an option to use the same value of the api key as the id but is not working for me. I've created an issue in github for that https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/2342

Comment: FWIW, the key id (assuming the key itself is valid) will be available in $context.identity.apiKeyId. You can use this to look up the key. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Comment: @nicowernli `sdk has an option to use the same value of the api key as the id` Where did you see this option? Did it work for you eventually to get the api key id from api key value?